# setWantsLayer changes behavior of NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, osx-elcapitan

I got an issue with `NSWindow` and it's content view - with appearance of title bar and rounded bottom corners to be specific. I'm observing the issue on 10.11 and on 10.10 everything looks fine. But to the point.

The title bar of the window looks like this:

[image: correct titlte bar]

and on the same time bottom looks like this:

[image]

No rounded corners.
Window is initiated programmatically and it consists of two subviews added programmatically, by using self.contentView addSubview: method.

After some work found out, that adding

```
[self.contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

at the beginning of window init the tittle bar looks like this:

[image]

Flat and solid darker than normal color - not good.
On the other hand bottom looks as I need it to look like:

[image]

I'm not allowed to show more of the windows.
And here's the init with my experiments:

```
[self.contentView setWantsLayer:YES];

self.identifier = someid;
self.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask;
self.backingType = NSBackingStoreBuffered;
[self setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowInitWidth, windowInitHeight) display:NO];
[self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorForKeyPath:@"blackcolor"]];
NSButton *windowButton = [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
[windowButton setEnabled:NO];
[self centerOnMainWindowScreen];

[self setupLeftPanel];
[self setupRightPanel];
[self setupConstraints];
```

Any help, that will explain why is this happening (what is the order of drawing window elements?) and how to properly init window, appreciated.
Once again: it's working fine on 10.10 both ways. 10.11 is causing corrupted drawing.

Comment: I think the darkened title bar is caused by the background color, not by the layer.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the content view alone and instead adding a subview that fills it and making that layer-backed?

Comment: @Sulthan - I tried changing color ([self setBackgroundColor:]) to black and white and not setting color. Bar is normal, when contentView is not layer-backed.

Comment: @KenThomases - Yes I did. I created new NSView and chained it to contentView (addSubiew). Behaviour is identical - corners on bottom not rounded - dark title bar when [intermediatelayer setWantsLayer:YES].

Comment: Could you create a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? I tried your code in my window but everything behaved correctly. The only change in title bar was caused by the background color (black background made the whole window dark).

Comment: @Sulthan, will do when have more time. Probably in the evening. Do you use El Capitan or Yosemite? issue does not exist on Yosemite.

Comment: @dobry I am on latest OS X with latest Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

After all, you guys were right. 
I wasn't able to create minimum complete and verifiable example, but I decided to change background color of the window to transparent color. 
I don't know why it was initially set to grey (it was grey when I got the task) but changing it to transparent is not affecting any components put on it later.

So this is a solution for me, but still, I wonder, why is title bar affected when window's contentView is layer backed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I *can* reproduce this reliably (most recently on macOS 10.12.2), so it's not just you. Save and run the below with `swift`:

```
import Cocoa

let window = NSWindow()
window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 100, height: 100))
window.center()

let layeredView = NSView(frame: window.contentView!.frame)
layeredView.autoresizingMask = [.viewWidthSizable, .viewHeightSizable]
layeredView.wantsLayer = true
layeredView.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
window.contentView!.addSubview(layeredView)

window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

NSApplication.shared().run()
```